# Set default select based on php value

Tags: php

So i have a select that should have default selection based on the value of a user ID. and if the user ID isn't present in the select, it should default to 0.

```
<option value="<?php echo $admin['value'] ?>" selected="<?php echo $this->getUser()->getid() ?>"><?php echo $admin['label'] ?></option>
```

I can get the default selected if the user ID is present, but i'm a little stuck on having it default to 0 if not present.

I'm sure this is easy

Comment: Post the code of your `getid()` method

Comment: selected="<?php echo $this->getUser()->getid() ?>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is wrong

You need to do this:

```
selected='selected'
```

php

```
<option value="<?php echo $admin['value'] ?>" <?php if($this->getUser()->getid() == $admin['value']) print "selected='selected'" ><?php echo $admin['label'] ?></option>
```

Comment: yeah my html was wrong, for sure. so the working result is: <option value="<?php echo $admin['value'] ?>" <?php if($userid == $admin['value']) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $admin['label'] ?></option>

Comment: however, i would still like an else statement to make the select id of 0 to be selected if $userid does not equal $admin['value']. But it's good enough for now

Comment: You should just add: isset($this->getUser()->getid()) in front the way php works, it will instantly stop the if and dont check the last part of it, this will make sure you dont get any warning if something is wrong with getUser() of getId()

Answer (score 1):

The `selected` property works like a boolean flag.

```
<select name="foo>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="baz" selected="selected">baz</option>
</select>
```

Only emit the `selected` property for the option you want to select. The value of the selected property doesn't actually matter; if it's a *non-empty* value the option will be selected.

Comment: Correct, and that's working. What i am after is the if statement to default to 0 if the selected ID isn't present. Maybe I'm not asking the right question.

Comment: Then add `<option value="0">default</option>` as the first option.